# Storyboard is complete, how do I get the code from it?

Tags: ios, storyboard

If one was to create an interface using the utility bar by dragging and dropping buttons, labels etc. Is there any way to get the code that makes the existing storyboard created? As in the code that produces the button and the label but for what you have created on that storyboard using the utility bar.

Comment: Down-voted and voted to close because this is **extremely** vague. Forget the "normal" thoughts about *"What have you tried?" or "What is your specific issue?"* - lets just go with **Do you know what `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` are?"** I may sound harsh but you've already had one answer stating upfront - "Not sure to understand...". Last thought - meant helpfully. A Storyboard opened in virtually any text editor is nothing but an XML file meant to be consumed by Xcode. (Very simplified, but true.) Is **that** what you are asking?

Comment: Interface Builder isn't a graphical tool that generates code.  It's a graphical tool that creates XML that describes a UI.  That UI is loaded by the Application class as defined in the Info.plist.  Classes are instantiated by the storyboard XML, not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand you well but:
Storyboards are xml files, you can view the generated code by clicking on the arrowed icon on the top-right corner of XCode :

[image: XCode version editor]

Comment: Is more easy than these, right click on Storyboard, Open As... >> Source code

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how to use these UI items, you should search on how to create **outlets** .

Some old example [here](https://oleb.net/blog/2011/06/creating-outlets-and-actions-via-drag-and-drop-in-xcode-4/)

If you are interesting to see the markup language for your interface you can open the file with any editor (including Xcode), but I don't see why you would need that.